# How to create responsive image cards?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically in my app I have image related cards of fruits. I'm stumped on making the card responsive.

At maximum width there are 5 cards per row showing an image of an orange. That works fine.

After I used media to adjust my flex-basis. So if the width is less than 1200px, then it will only show 4 image cards. It will keep adjusting as the width decreasing all the way to 1 card. E.g.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .card {
    flex-basis: 25%;
  }
}
```

The part that I'm stumped on is this. If flex-basis is 100% (screen width is <700px), then the image gets cropped out. Like this: [image]

I used `background-size: cover;`. I have no idea how to fix this.

This is my code:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
  background: black;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  height: 200px;
}

.card-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/dudegkgw9/image/upload/v1655351737/cloudinary_riys5j.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .card {
    flex-basis: 25%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .card {
    flex-basis: 33.333%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .card {
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-image">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-image">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-image">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-image">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want the show the whole picture of 3 orange particles? then you should play with your `.card` height property. cause with 200px the card is smaller than the image.

Comment: I just Increased the height and it fixes it, but now it looks massive at low width. No way to fit 200 height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is probably what you need `background-size: 100% 100%;` for .card-image.
it would be best if you changed your breakpoints now.

watch the snippet in full-page

```css
image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
    background: black;
    flex-basis: 20%;
    height: 200px;
}

.card-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/dudegkgw9/image/upload/v1655351737/cloudinary_riys5j.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .card {
        flex-basis: 25%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .card {
        flex-basis: 33.333%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .card {
        flex-basis: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>


</html>
```

---

Or if you want your images to responsively fit the container, do as below:

```css
image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
    background: black;
    flex-basis: 20%;
    height: 200px;
}

.card-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/dudegkgw9/image/upload/v1655351737/cloudinary_riys5j.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-size: cover; /* <------ */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .card {
        flex-basis: 25%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .card {
        flex-basis: 33.333%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .card {
        flex-basis: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-image">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>


</html>
```